# How does Reachability class work under the hood

Tags: ios, networking, reachability, internet-connection

I am planning to integrate this Reachability class in my application - https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift But I have some trouble understanding how it achieves getting network updates. Does it ping some website regularly, does it rely on operating system updates or something else? Is it battery consuming to use it? Thanks in advance. I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464364/how-does-the-ios-reachability-class-work-and-why-the-ip-address-169-254-0-0) but don't find it sufficient.

Comment: It is just a Swift wrapper around the network reachability function in the System Configuration framework. It uses that framework to monitor the ability to reach a nominated host and reports back the network interface used to reach it. The reachability check is triggered by a network connectivity change so I wouldn't expect it to have a major impact on battery life.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for responding. If it is monitoring the ability to reach some host, doesn't it mean it pings it on some amount of time which will result in battery consumption or I don't get it right.

Comment: No, because iOS knows when there is a change in connectivity; when it connects or disconnects from wifi or when the cellular network comes and goes or when airplane mode turns on or off, for example. Only when the network path changes does it need to try and connect to the target host.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you. If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.